# sqoop import communications link falilure

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, sqoop

I am getting below error while importing a MySQL table using Sqoop to HDFS.
as MySQL is on my Name node and rest slaves are on different VMs, for this I also edited the MySQL confide file and disables the **bind-address 0.0.0.0**, still no progress.
replies much appreciated, thanks.

FYI, I am using a hadoop multinode cluster.

```
adminn@master:~/sqoop/bin$ sqoop import --connect jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb?characterEncoding=latin1 --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver --username root --password xxxxxx --table sample --m 1

Warning: /home/adminn/sqoop/../hbase does not exist! HBase imports will fail.
Please set $HBASE_HOME to the root of your HBase installation.
Warning: /home/adminn/sqoop/../hcatalog does not exist! HCatalog jobs will fail.
Please set $HCAT_HOME to the root of your HCatalog installation.
Warning: /home/adminn/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
Warning: /home/adminn/sqoop/../zookeeper does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ZOOKEEPER_HOME to the root of your Zookeeper installation.
/home/adminn/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2358: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_USER: invalid variable name
/home/adminn/hadoop/libexec/hadoop-functions.sh: line 2453: HADOOP_ORG.APACHE.SQOOP.SQOOP_OPTS: invalid variable name
2022-12-30 10:31:24,292 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.7
2022-12-30 10:31:24,320 WARN tool.BaseSqoopTool: Setting your password on the command-line is insecure. Consider using -P instead.
2022-12-30 10:31:24,390 WARN sqoop.ConnFactory: Parameter --driver is set to an explicit driver however appropriate connection manager is not being set (via --connection-manager). Sqoop is going to fall back to org.apache.sqoop.manager.GenericJdbcManager. Please specify explicitly which connection manager should be used next time.

2022-12-30 10:31:24,423 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000

2022-12-30 10:31:24,423 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation

2022-12-30 10:31:24,735 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM sample AS t WHERE 1=0

2022-12-30 10:31:24,745 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM sample AS t WHERE 1=0

2022-12-30 10:31:24,800 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /home/adminn/hadoop

Note: /tmp/sqoop-adminn/compile/db6838afbd83c3028b82196f2fa2d7c9/sample.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.

Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

2022-12-30 10:31:26,707 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-adminn/compile/db6838afbd83c3028b82196f2fa2d7c9/sample.jar

2022-12-30 10:31:26,756 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Beginning import of sample

2022-12-30 10:31:26,757 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.tracker is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.jobtracker.address

2022-12-30 10:31:26,876 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar

2022-12-30 10:31:26,879 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM sample AS t WHERE 1=0

2022-12-30 10:31:27,509 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps

2022-12-30 10:31:27,653 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /192.168.0.15:8032

2022-12-30 10:31:28,352 INFO mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Disabling Erasure Coding for path: /tmp/hadoop-yarn/staging/adminn/.staging/job_1672373403508_0004

2022-12-30 10:31:32,595 INFO db.DBInputFormat: Using read commited transaction isolation

2022-12-30 10:31:32,799 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1

2022-12-30 10:31:32,915 INFO Configuration.deprecation: yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled is deprecated. Instead, use yarn.system-metrics-publisher.enabled

2022-12-30 10:31:33,190 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1672373403508_0004

2022-12-30 10:31:33,192 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Executing with tokens: []

2022-12-30 10:31:33,490 INFO conf.Configuration: resource-types.xml not found

2022-12-30 10:31:33,491 INFO resource.ResourceUtils: Unable to find 'resource-types.xml'.

2022-12-30 10:31:34,186 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1672373403508_0004

2022-12-30 10:31:34,278 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://master:8088/proxy/application_1672373403508_0004/

2022-12-30 10:31:34,280 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1672373403508_0004

2022-12-30 10:31:48,004 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1672373403508_0004 running in uber mode : false

2022-12-30 10:31:48,006 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%

2022-12-30 10:31:55,129 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1672373403508_0004_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)

    ... 10 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:787)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)

    ... 11 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)

    ... 24 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:262)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:293)

    ... 25 more



2022-12-30 10:32:01,340 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1672373403508_0004_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)

    ... 10 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:787)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)

    ... 11 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)

    ... 24 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:262)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:293)

    ... 25 more



2022-12-30 10:32:08,436 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1672373403508_0004_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED

Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:170)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setConf(DBInputFormat.java:161)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.setConf(ReflectionUtils.java:77)

    at org.apache.hadoop.util.ReflectionUtils.newInstance(ReflectionUtils.java:137)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:347)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:174)

    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)

    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1729)

    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:168)

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:223)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.setDbConf(DBInputFormat.java:168)

    ... 10 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:787)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)

    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:247)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBConfiguration.getConnection(DBConfiguration.java:302)

    at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBInputFormat.getConnection(DBInputFormat.java:216)

    ... 11 more

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure



The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)

    ... 24 more

Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)

    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)

    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)

    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:607)

    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:556)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:452)

    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:262)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)

    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:293)

    ... 25 more



2022-12-30 10:32:15,557 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%

2022-12-30 10:32:15,607 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1672373403508_0004 failed with state FAILED due to: Task failed task_1672373403508_0004_m_000000

Job failed as tasks failed. failedMaps:1 failedReduces:0 killedMaps:0 killedReduces: 0



2022-12-30 10:32:15,805 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 8

    Job Counters 

        Failed map tasks=4

        Launched map tasks=4

        Other local map tasks=4

        Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=38808

        Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=0

        Total time spent by all map tasks (ms)=19404

        Total vcore-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=19404

        Total megabyte-milliseconds taken by all map tasks=4967424

2022-12-30 10:32:15,819 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group FileSystemCounters is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.FileSystemCounter instead

2022-12-30 10:32:15,825 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Transferred 0 bytes in 48.2897 seconds (0 bytes/sec)

2022-12-30 10:32:15,830 WARN mapreduce.Counters: Group org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Task$Counter is deprecated. Use org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.TaskCounter instead

2022-12-30 10:32:15,831 INFO mapreduce.ImportJobBase: Retrieved 0 records.

2022-12-30 10:32:15,831 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Import failed: Import job failed!

adminn@master:~/sqoop/bin$ B
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use localhost for database string. Use the full IP or hostname since the mapreduce command will be distributed in the network

You should not disable bind address 0.0.0.0, as that is what controls external network access.

It's also encountered not to run mysql on any of the Hadoop servers.